# What is the "default font family" analogue of `\mathbf`, `\mathit`, `\mathrm`, etc.?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, bold, math-fonts, text-decorations

I was recently editing a MO post in which a user wanted to name a property depending on a real parameter `$c$`.  The name was originally typeset as `$\bf (P_c)$`, but, of course, this puts the `$c$`, as well as the rest of the property name, in boldface.  If it were just the $P$ that was to be bolded, then one could easily do `($\mathbf P_c$)`, but this user had bolded the parentheses, and I wanted to respect the original notation as much as possible.

A clumsy solution on which I settled was `$\mathbf(\mathbf P_c\mathbf)$`.  (Of course the first two invocations could be condensed to `$\mathbf{(P}_c\mathbf)$`, but that looked even uglier to me.)  However, it would easier if there were some "undo `\mathbf`" command like (to make up a random name) `\mathplain`, in which case I could do `$\mathbf{(P_{\mathplain c})}$`.  Does such a command exist?  If not, is there any better way of simulating it than the clumsy approach that I took?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\mathnormal` is the command you want: `$\mathbf{(P_{\mathnormal{c}})}$`. However, `\mathbf` doesn't actually make parentheses bold. You can use `\boldsymbol` (from `amsmath`) around just the parentheses if you really wanted that. Here's an MWE that shows the difference:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\(\mathbf{(P_{\mathnormal{c}})}\)

\(\boldsymbol{(} \mathbf{P_{\mathnormal{c}}} \boldsymbol{)}\)

\end{document}
```

[image: mathbf vs boldsymbol]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, and thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for. \\ Good point about `\mathbf` + parentheses in LaTeX.  I *think* that `\mathbf(` is slightly different from `(` when run through MathJax, though, even looking at the two side by side, I'm not 100% sure.  (But, of course, this site isn't about MathJax.)

Answer (score 2):

Use proper markup.

In order to get bold parentheses, you need `\bm` (or `\boldsymbol`, but `\bm` is definitely better).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\[
\bm{(}\mathbf{P}_{c}\bm{)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, take into account that `\bf` has been deprecated for around 30 years. Also `\mathbf{P}` should be preferred to `\mathbf P`.

Comment: Thank you for the point about parentheses, which @bonk also [mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706515), and for the pointer to [bm](https://ctan.org/pkg/bm).  The `\bf` was not in my code, but in the original code that I was editing.  For the rest, this seems to answer the question of how to do what I actually did better, but not how to do what I wanted to do (which @‍bonk [answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706515): the command I am looking for is `\mathnormal`).

Comment: @LSpice I beg to disagree: you asked the wrong question. 